# Extracting contents inside of found boundary python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to extract part of the image and save it as a separate image that is inside the boundary. I have extracted and drawn the boundary as follows:

```
cnts, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(gray.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for contour in cnts:
    print(cv2.boundingRect(contour))
cv2.drawContours(img,cnts,-1,(125,125,0),3 )
cv2.imshow('contours',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can I obtain the image inside the boundary as a separate image? Here is my image:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are already painting the background in black. What do you mean by a separate image? The same image without the black margin?with the boundingRect you should be able to do that: create a new image with the same width and height as the bounding rect and then copy one in the other

Answer (score 1):

You should find the bounding rectangle and then save it to a new image

Something like that:

```
r = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
crop_img = im[r[1]:r[1]+r[3], r[0]:r[0]+r[2]]
cv2.imwrite('roi.png', crop_img)
```

Because numpy slicing expects y:y+h, x:x+h

If you want the oriented bounding box, use minAreaRect

EDIT:

You say that you want just the rice grain. As any image is rectangular, you will always have some background. What you can do is paint the background black:

- create a black image with the size of the original image (the one with many rice grains)
- drawContours() with the thickness=CV_FILLED (or any negative number) and color white. It should be black image with only one rice grain in white. Let's call that "mask"
- Then do the bitwise_and of your original image and the "mask"
- Then do the crop (boundingRect) explained above

If you want all of the grains of rice, you should do all that inside the for

Comment: I want to find the border of the rice grain, and save that grain as a separate image. I might have many rice grains in a picture, this is just the simplest example for me to start.

Comment: I get rectangular picture most of them are black, I want the picture of the rice in on picture, just the rice, how can I do that?